# querySelectorAll not working it seems.Getting an empty NodeList

Tags: javascript, queryselector

**JS + HTML**

```js
var selector=document.querySelectorAll('.selected_icon');
console.log(selector);
```

```html
<div class="menu-icon-bar">
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon" > format_bold</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_italic</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_italic</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_underlined</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">content_cut</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">content_copy</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">content_paste</div>
   <select class="font_family_selector">
      <option value="Hello" selected>Hello</option>
      <option value="Hello1">Hello2</option>
      <option value="Hello3">Hello3</option>
      <option value=""></option>
   </select>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon ">format_align_left</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_align_right</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_align_justify</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_color_text</div>
   <div class="material-icons menu-icon select selected_icon">format_color_fill</div>
</div>
```

I expect it to log a non-empty Nodelist but it gives me an empty Nodelist. What is wrong with my code??

Comment: Where are you adding your code? If it's before the DOM has loaded it will return nothing. If you add your code just before the `</body>` tag, for example,  you will get the result you want. [`var selector=document.querySelectorAll('.selected_icon');` does return a nodelist](https://jsfiddle.net/q3wkmc95/).

Comment: @Andy Thanks it worked.I was using the script tag in the head section before the body